# How to point Load Balancer to my Existing Wordpress Installation in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, url-mapping

So I Install and set up new a WordPress installation via Google Cloud. I Also set up HTTP/s Load Balancer for cloud CDN. The LB is now working. Please help on how I can connect this too? so that my site will run with the cloud CDN. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you would like to setup HTTP(S) Load Balancer for Cloud CDN, you need to configure at least Backend and Frontend configuration at “HTTP(S) Load Balancing”.

In Load Balancing Backend configuration you have the option of selecting Instance Group. So before creating “backend service” you need to create a instance group. Since you already created WordPress VM instance, you should create a [unmanaged instances group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances). In Backend configuration then you will have the option of [Enable Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cdn) and selecting Health Check. So along with Instance Group please also create a Health Check following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks).

After completing Backend configuration you will have to configure [the Frontend](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-load-balancer-setup-tweaking-and-observations-c12d704e6d52) which is very straight forward.The front end is your virtual IP (VIP) or called anycast IP in GCP. One front end can service multiple regions (backends). In most cases you would want a static or reserved IP and not the default ephemeral. This way you can easily point an a-record on your Cloud DNS zone file to your load balancer IP.